# Is there any research or statistics that show adding share links to your site content areas increases sharing?

Tags: seo

Just wondering if there is any documentation out there that having share links to your content actually encourages and increases sharing of the content?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything for websites, but I found this about email. Admittedly it's from a vendor selling share-to-social service, but it does have some stats:

http://www.silverpop.com/news/press/share-to-social-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

If your question is, "does having sharing buttons on your site result in more shares compared with having no sharing buttons", then I think the answer's likely to be a resounding "yes!", purely from experience of adding social buttons to my own sites and to customers' sites; it has always increased shares, even on low-traffic sites.

If you're still in any doubt, though, you could test it for yourself. The [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com) service has a [detailed analytics feature](http://www.addthis.com/help/analytics-overview) that gives you an overview of the numbers of shares and incoming traffic you're getting from each social network.

Answer (score 0):

We don't think much happens here as we had added addthis share / connect on our website, only  for initial few days there were few clicks thereon nothing is happening.